# Why so many calls to same function?

Tags: python

I am not sure what I am missing here but see my code below

```
def TestLogger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE)
    handler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))
    handler.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

def printme( str ):
    logger = TestLogger(__name__)
    logger.debug( str)
    return

def main(args=None):
    logger = TestLogger(__name__)
    printme("1");
    printme("2");
    printme("3");

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In return, I expecvted only three lines but I get so many...
What am I missing here?
Output:

```
09:45:00,017 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  1 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16
09:45:00,017 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  1 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16 
09:45:00,018 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  2 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16 
09:45:00,018 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  2 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16
09:45:00,018 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  2 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16 
09:45:00,019 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  3 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16 
09:45:00,019 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  3 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16 
09:45:00,019 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  3 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61 2019-05-16 
09:45:00,019 [DEBUG]:[__main__]:  3 in C:/demo/TryMe.py:61
```

Comment: You have two instances of `logger`, one local to `printme`, the other is local to `main`, so each has a call to `debug`

Comment: @C.Nivs But it's never calling `logger.debug()` with the one in `main`.

Comment: Also, can you show how `TestLogger` is defined?

Comment: It's interesting that 1 is printed twice, and 2 is printed three times, and 3 is printed four times. These numbers also correspond to the number of times that `TestLogger(__name__)` was called before that point. I wonder if these are connected... If you added another `TestLogger(__name__)` at the top of `printme`, I wonder if the numbers would be printed three, five, and seven times?

Comment: Added code for testlogger....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `TestLogger` it adds another handler to the logger. Each handler prints a log message.

You call it once in `main()`. Then when you call `printme("1")` you call it again. So it logs `1` twice.

When you call `printme("2")` you call it a third time, so it logs `2` three times.

When you call `printme("3")` you call it once more, so it logs `3` four times.

You should just call `TestLogger()` once, and pass it as an argument to `printme()`.

```
def printme( str, logger ):
    logger.debug( str)
    return

def main(args=None):
    logger = TestLogger(__name__)
    printme("1", logger);
    printme("2", logger);
    printme("3", logger);
```

This would also be a reasonable use for a global variable, rather than having to pass `logger` as a parameter to every function that might need to do logging.

Or you can put `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in all the functions other than `main()`. This will get the logger that was configured by `TestLogger()`.

Comment: Yes, this was the reason. Thank you. Document says that each function should create logger so it can log module name....But this is the risk

Comment: @BeHappy Every function may fetch/create a logger, but only one should configure it!